# Keyword not supported: 'provider' with SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, sqlbulkcopy

I try to write access connection string in SqlBulkCopy but I got error **Keyword not supported: 'provider'**

here is my code:

```
bulk = New SqlBulkCopy("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mFileName & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=hmis;")
bulk.DestinationTableName = "Advance"
bulk.WriteToServer(dt_table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) only works with SQL Server. The constructor you are trying to call, [SqlBulkCopy(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x2hdfta.aspx) expects a valid connection string for SQL Server. The connection string you passed works only with Access.

Different databases products have different mechanisms for bulk import operations. You can't use a class created for one database product to import data to another.

Microsoft Access has no bulk import support.

Comment: any other option like SqlBulkCopy to copy data from datatable to access db

Answer (score 0):

The [SQLBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) is only supported with SQL Server connection string. You can't use other types of Connection Strings..

Comment: any other option like SqlBulkCopy to copy data from datatable to access db

Comment: It highly depends of the kind of data you have. You can run specific MS Access SQL to import data from text files for example.